# How to provision Vagrant to set a proxy and use it?

Tags: proxy, vagrant

I have the following setup:

- Windows 7 computer
- Installation of Ruby, Vagrant, VirtualBox
- VBox image Ubuntu 14.x
- Working in the intranet of my company that needs a proxy to access the internet

I am able to configure the VBox image for the user vagrant to access the internet by setting the environment variable `http_proxy` to our proxy. However, when I try to set the proxy in a shell provisioner, I have problems. Here are the parts of the script that define the proxy, and the parts that make the first access to the internet:

```
# Base setup proxy and DISPLAY
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.name.com:8080
echo "Add proxy to necessary parts"
echo 'export http_proxy=http://proxy.name.com:8080' >> ~vagrant/.bash_profile
echo 'export DISPLAY=192.168.137.1:0.0' >> ~vagrant/.bash_profile
echo 'export http_proxy=http://proxy.name.com:8080' >> /root/.bash_profile
export http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY

# Install Git
echo "Install Git"
apt-get update
apt-get install -y git
...
```

However, I get the following output:

```
Add proxy to necessary parts
Install Git
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
...
```

How can I set inside a Unix script the proxy and use it immediately, so that `apt-get`, `git clone`, ... could be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a plugin for it!

Install [vagrant-proxyconf](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf):

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

Configure it (in *$HOME/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile* for all Vagrant VMs):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http     = "http://10.206.246.20:8080"
    config.proxy.https    = "http://10.206.246.20:8080"
    config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
  end
end
```

Comment: Will give it a try when I am in my company network again. Thank's for the idea!

Comment: Worked like a charm. That is the more canonical solution, so I have taken this one instead of the one by f01

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it works, removed `set`:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://10.206.246.20:8080
export http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY
```

Comment: I will check this, and will come back in a minute. But looks promising (don't remember where SET is necessary, Windows?).

Comment: In BASH, `set` is for setting shell options stuff. :)

Comment: Worked, found the next syntax error, but now I am able to get things from the internet. Great!

Comment: I have marked the solution by tmatilai as the right one, because it is the solution that fits much better.

Comment: In Bash we use "export", in Fish we use "set". Windows, what is that?